# Design and coding patterns in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT and have a general question.
To distinguish two elements with different attributes, it is better (also for performance) to use `<xsl:template match="foo[@aOne]">` and `<xsl:template match="foo[@aTwo]">`
instead of an `<xsl:if test="@aOne">` within one single template. And as far as I understood, this is how one should "think" in XSLT. But in my oppinion, this has the disadvantage, that it leads to redundant parts of code.

For example: The matching of an element with two attributes

```
<foo aOne="asdf">
   ...
</foo>

<foo aTwo="asdf">
   ...
</foo>
```

The template would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="foo[@aOne]">
    <div>
      <p> 
         <xsl:value-of select="@aOne"/>
      </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="foo[@aTwo]">
    <div>
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="@aTwo"/>
      </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

So one would have to write all the *frame* (like the `<div>` etc. in the example) several times.

Is there some kind of *template design pattern* like it is known from Java?

Or is it a totally wrong approach / view on programming XSLT?

Hope my idea got clear, thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: You ask about a _template design pattern_, and yes, there are several coding patterns, the most famous ones being the [copy idiom aka identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), [summation pattern](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect1/N169.html), shallow skip templates and [Münchian grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping) (XSLT 1.0 only). Search for XSLT design patterns to find a bunch more, including some papers. Also, the XSLT Cookbook 1st and 2nd edition contains a lot of design patterns.

Comment: PS, I removed "performance" from your title, because there's nothing inherently unperformant in your code, or that requires special attention, regardless the way you write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Abel: Your links led me to the answers I was looking for.

Also found an online cookbook with a lot of usefull hints for good code design in XSLT

http://users.atw.hu/xsltcookbook2/index.html

Especially this part was helpful, as I asked for the "template" pattern as known from Java. It describes how to implement object-oriented reuse in XSLT.

http://users.atw.hu/xsltcookbook2/xsltckbk2-chp-6-sect-6.html

Answer (score 2):

Are the two attributes mutually exclusive? If so, I would write

```
<xsl:template match="foo[@aOne|@aTwo]">
    <div>
      <p> 
         <xsl:value-of select="@aOne|@aTwo"/>
      </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

If they are not mutually exclusive, then your approach of having two template rules seems inadequate: there would be four rules for the four possible combinations of @aOne being absent or present, and @aTwo being absent or present.

Comment: Is there a way, to avoid the redundant code (In the example the `<div>` and `<p>` tags) when having multiple rules, which are just "slightly" different?

Comment: @bauz: that's all what XSLT is about, making it easy to prevent you from writing redundant templates. Both Michael's here have given you ways of writing your code differently. It highly depends on whatever your project is, what the best approach is. This is no different from other programming languages. A good technical design will yield a good product.

Comment: @bauz It depends on what the slight difference is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to draw any general rules. I think that in your specific example, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <div>
        <p> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@aOne | @aTwo">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

or even:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <div>
        <p> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@aOne | @aTwo"/>
        </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

or some other variation (we don't know enough about what the input may contain).